# libGdx: Can't load assets from JUnit test class

Tags: java, junit, libgdx, asset-management

I'm currently facing the following problem:
I started a project using libGdx. I've almost finished it and want to run some JUnit tests now. In the test class I'm using an AssetManager to load assets from the src module, but however it doesn't work correctly.

```
assetManager.setLoader(SceneAsset.class, ".gltf", new GLTFAssetLoader());

assetManager.load("faceted_character/scene.gltf", SceneAsset.class);
assetManager.load("cute_cyborg/scene.gltf", SceneAsset.class);
assetManager.load("spaceship_orion/scene.gltf", SceneAsset.class);

assetManager.finishLoading();`
```

It throws this error:
[image: stacktrace]

(line 49 is assetManager.finishLoading();)

This leads me to the question: How can I access these files from the test class?

Comment: Want to note that I already tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122554/libgdx-test-from-gradle-command-line-assets-not-found without success